# working of pthread_join(tid,&retval);

Tags: synchronization, multithreading, deadlock

Why main function calling pthread_join(tid,&retval) does not wait for thread with thread id equal to tid to close?

Details - I am trying to create simple file copying program with multi-threading so that I can learn more about mutex locks,semaphores and deadlocks but without using sleep() in main thread my program terminates without copying data or incomplete copying.Note I am calling pthread_exit(retval) in the sub-thread.

Here is code
http://ideone.com/mexxmk
Here is another code which runs infinite counter in order to check whether sub thread ends prematurely even when pthread_join is called.
http://ideone.com/0DIxUK --- Result : It does not end prematurely.In the latter code main thread does wait for sub thread to close.
So why the first code is not behaving in that way.

Comment: Did you call pthread_detach(tid) or create the thread in a detached state using pthread_attr_setdetachedstate()?

Comment: No I do not know about them and I did not call them.Should I post source code?

Comment: Yes, posting the code will be helpful -- thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I do not know posting code on this site so I used ideone.com site.And some fields are redundant in code and comments are useless they are made to just do experimentation.

Comment: Are you sure that `capsule->val1` is non-zero?  I suggest you try to create a simple example that exercises the code you're having trouble with.  Maybe have a thread that counts to 10 with a 1 second pause in between.  Create it, let it run, do a pthread_join() against it, see that pthread_join() is behaving the way you expect. Then start gradually adding complexity.

Comment: Sorry but problem is solved I just made silly mistake there .I assigned return value of pthread_create to tid1 and tid2 ,and this is wrong as pthread_create returns integer and not thread ID.

Answer (score 0):

One method (that assumes the threads actually complete, among other possible gotchas I haven't learned about yet) is to use a mutex, or something along the lines of:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t Lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t Job_Done = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

unsigned long Threads_Completed;

void *worker(void *unused);

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t *tids;
    struct timespec wait;

    if ((tids = calloc(sizeof(pthread_t), 42)) == NULL)
        err(EX_OSERR, "could not calloc() threads list");

    fprintf(stderr, "dbg starting...\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, worker, NULL) != 0)
            err(EX_OSERR, "could not pthread_create() thread %u", i);
    }

    wait.tv_sec = 7;
    wait.tv_nsec = 0;

    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&Lock);
        if (Threads_Completed == 42)
            break;
        pthread_cond_timedwait(&Job_Done, &Lock, &wait);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&Lock);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "dbg all done!\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *worker(void *unused)
{
    sleep(3 + rand() % 7);     // actual work here
    fprintf(stderr, "dbg done!\n");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&Lock);
    Threads_Completed++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Lock);
    pthread_cond_signal(&Job_Done);

    return (void *) 0;
}
```

Comment: Something like that will work, but is unnecessary since pthread_join() will do that for you.  pthread_join() isn't the problem.

Comment: @VishvajeetPatil I stand by my previous suggestion.  You're trying to write and test too much code at once.  I suggest that you start with a working pthread_create/pthread_join then gradually add --- and test --- a little bit of code at a time.  That'll be the easiest way to track down what's going wrong.